# SSO using saml2.0 in opensaml

Tags: java, authentication, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, opensaml

We have 4 applications. And we want to implement SSO across these apps. I have several doubts regarding this. We were suggested to use opensaml.

Query 1:

The username and password entered by the user is sent by client(Ex.Front-end) to the middleware and then the middleware send this information to the SSO server,Then in this case
Is the user a principal??
Is the middleware a Service Provider?
Is the SSO server a Identity Provider?

Query 2:

Now when an user logins in one of the application then we should connect to Identity Provider to initiate the SSO, what parameters(Mandatory) should be sent the by us to SSO server??

Query 3:

When After getting response from SSO server, Should middleware keep the token for future reference?

Query 4:

Now if the another user hits another application then it should be identified that there is sso working on. How to identify that? 
Should the middleware hit the SSO server for that?

Kindly resolve above queries.

Comment: Kindly resolve these queries ASAP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes, the 'middleware' you describe is the Service Provider and the 'SSO server' is the Identity Provider.

2) When the user attempts a protected resource on the Service Provider, it will redirect the browser to the Identity Provider. If the browser does not have an active session with the Identity Provider the user will be prompted for login details.

Following which the browser will be redirected back to the Service Provider along with the SAML response authenticating the user. After verifying the SAML response the Service Provider will redirect to the protected resource.

Once the user is authenticated the Service Provider can keep it's own session to save redirecting to the Identity Provider for every request.

3) The Service Provider (middleware) would not normally keep the SAML response from the Identity Provider, instead it can set up it's own session. For example in .Net this can be down via Forms Authentication.

4) When the user tries to access another Service Provider, the browser will be redirected to the Identity Provider. As the user already has an active session, the Identity Provider will redirect back to the Service Provider with the SAML repsonse. The service provider will then redirect to the protected resource and optionally create it's own session.

This happens seamlessly to the user, and they are effectively logged straight into the second Service Provider.

Also which platform are you using for development? If you are using .NET or Java then I can recommend the open source library [OIOSAML](http://digitaliser.dk/group/42063/resources). It includes working examples of both Service and Identity Providers so you can see how things work.

Comment: Thanks for resolving the queries. Still I have some doubts.

Comment: I thoroughly understood the role of identity Provider  But is there something URL kind of thing that we have to hit for IDP(Identity Provider)? Also I am using Java so we need to send some request which has some particular format so that format is being created by programmer or is there any kind of library in java in which we can set the parameters and request will be made automatically in particular format??

Comment: Yes, you will have a sign-on url on the Identity Provider. If the Service Provider doesn't have an active session, it will redirect the browser to the Identity Providers sign-on url, with the return url as a parameter. After successful authentication the Identity Provider will reddrect back along with the SAML response.  So it is all handled by broswer redirects, which allows access to the session cookies on each site.

Comment: With regards Java, it seems there is a Java version of OIOSAML that I mentioned above. I highly recommend checking it out even just to follow the examples and get a better understaning, it's open source, well written with good documentation.

Comment: I am not able to find the java examples. Please help so that I can integrate SSO in varios apps.

Comment: The current version at the link above is oiosaml.java-9918.zip. It has demo documentation at /doc/installation.html.

Answer (score 1):

What IDP are you thinking of using?

In the SAML world, all the URL's, certificates etc. are exchanged via metadata.

So in the IDP you would import sp.xml and in the SP you would import idp.xml.

For Java, you would need some kind of SAML stack on your SP side.

Refer: [SAML stack](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-stack.html) and [Java equivalent to WIF](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/wif-is-there-java-equivalent.html).

Comment: In this java equivalent to WIF, it is using Apche CXF thats the different framework. I have heard about opensaml library. But i am not able to find the examples for this. Any suggestion in this?

Comment: If you want to go openSAML, manuals etc. here - https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/Home.